# For loop not doing what intended

Tags: c

This is a for loop for printing prime numbers in a given range and at the end printing how many prime numbers were in the given range. The program is also printing 1 as prime.

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a,b,k,c,s=0;

    printf("Enter the start : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter the end : ");
    scanf("%d",&b);

    for( ;a<=b;a++){
    k = 1;
        for(c=2;c<=a/2;c++){
            if(a%c==0) {
                k-=1;
                break;
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
        (k!=0)?(printf("%d ",a),s+=1):printf("");
    }
    printf("\nNo. of Primes : %d",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the start : 1
Enter the end : 25
1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 
No. of Primes : 10
```

I want to know how to change the code to only get primes.

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: add `if (start == 1) start = 2;`

Comment: what is your question? And what do you expect your program to print out?

Comment: I just want it to print only the prime numbers.

Comment: Your code is poorly readable and inefficient, but IMO it works fine. What is the problem? What output do you get and what output do you expect. Please [edit]  your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get `1` shown as a result because you set

```
k = 1;
```

and the following loop

```
for(c=2;c<=a/2;c++){
...
```

does not change this if `a` is `1` because `c <= a` is not fulfilled.

Replace

```
k = 1;
```

with

```
if(a > 1) k = 1;
else k = 0;
```

The code in the loop

```
    for(c=2;c<=a/2;c++){
        if(a%c==0){
        k-=1;break;}
        else continue;
    }
```

is a bit strange.

Instead of `k-=1;` I would write `k=0;` because this makes clear that you want the value to become `0`. You can remove `else continue;` because this is what the loop would do anyway.

Comment: @BeninCwithD No need for greetings or thanks here. If an answer solves your problem you can simply accept it using the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

Your code that tests for a prime will also pass for the number `1`. The inner `for` loop is not entered in this case, so `k` is never set to zero, and the line `(k != 0) ? (printf("%d ", a), s += 1) : printf("");` takes the true branch.

Simple fix:

```
(k != 0 && a != 1) ? ...
```